# Mac runs same vm. Cannot exit

Tags: mac, windows, startup, restore

I have inherited some Mac-based machine, but when I power it on - virtual machine with Windows XP starts. I cannot figure, how to exit this mode or restore Mac to factory defaults. I tried booting with pressing <kbd>Fx</kbd> keys, <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>.

Nothing works, and Windows XP is booting normally.

Comment: if it was Bootcamped correctly, Windows will have a task bar icon, Bootcamp, which will let you switch back to Mac; that will set Mac as default, too.

Answer (score 3):

Hold down the Option key (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) when your Mac starts. That should take you to the startup selection screen. Hopefully it'll show you an icon for Windows and another icon for OSX.

http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1310

If it doesn't then you might need to install OSX from scratch. If your Mac is fairly recent you can do this from the Internet directly. Otherwise you'll need to source install media.

http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT4718

Answer (score 0):

OP says that a "virtual machine" starts. One wonders if it is a startup item and that just loads immediately on startup. If so holding the SHIFT key at startup should disable any startup items.

Failing that the OPTION key at startup that Alistair mentioned will allow you to choose a boot partition and boot into Mac O/S if it is installed. Note that it is possible to not install Mac O/S on a Mac and just boot into Windows by default.